# Potential data loss with stereo_image_proc

Tags: opencv, pcl, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been messing around with the point clouds generated by stereo_image_proc for the bumblebee2 for a little bit now.  I have just applied the toROSMsg command to convert my point clouds to opencv images and realized that there are many gapping holes in my images.

Is this a universal tendency for stereo_image_proc? Or is this an indication that I need to do much more parameter tuning via rqt_reconfigure?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63014/potential-data-loss-with-stereo_image_proc/) by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2013-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the artifacts you are seeing are related to how stereo block matching works. Parameter tuning will allow some optimization, but noise and gaps in stereo point clouds should be expected and will not go away completely in any but the most controlled scenarios.

The ["Choosing good stereo parameters"](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters) tutorial provides some help on what the knobs are with regards to hopefully improving results.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1